# Working on orbital mechanics...need to find the length of arc d along the Earth's surface. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Tags: trigonometry, arc-length

[image]

I know the radius of the Earth and the radius of the orbit (r). I need to find the length of arc (d) along the surface of the Earth given the graphical information presented. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: It would help if you could describe your picture in words, or any other context you would like to provide. For example, what is the $120^\circ$? Just answering that question I asked, however, is not enough to meet the quality standards of asking a question on this site.

Comment: If $\theta$ is in radians, then $d=\theta R_E$. If $\theta$ is in degrees, then $d=\frac{\theta}{180^\circ}\pi R_E$.

Comment: You need one more piece of information to make this solvable. For instance, it is solvable if the vertex of the $120^\circ$ angle were on the bisector of the central angle, it could be solved. More generally if you knew the angle of elavation of either side of the $120^\circ$ angle, it would be solvable.